# I would like to change my primary email on GitHub, but I have some questions

Tags: github

I have a GitHub account linked to my Gmail address, and I've decided to switch to another email service. I have some questions. Currently, my primary email address on GitHub is still Gmail, and I have a GPG key associated with that Gmail address to sign my commits on GitHub. If I change my primary email address on GitHub, what will happen? Is there any issue? Do I need to generate a new GPG key? Or can I add two email addresses to the existing GPG key, so GitHub won't mark the old commits as unverified? If the old commits remain associated with the old email address, is there any negative impact, aside from them being displayed that way in the logs, purely from an aesthetic perspective? I would be grateful for any suggestion.